# DynamoDB get item but only if an attribute in that item is false

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

So I have a an item I only want to get if its not set to be deleted.

Is it more efficient to sort it away in Node after I have fetched it? I cannot find any conditions in the documentation in the get call to dynamodb. How do I approach this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set in params isDeleted:false. Doing so you can filter by any attribute you want, not only by isDeleted. See the example:

```
 var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

 AWS.config.update({
   region: "us-west-2",
   endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
 });

 var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


 var params = {
     isDeleted : false
 };

 docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
         console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
     } else {
         console.log("Query succeeded.");
     }
 });
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Looks like it, yes. Do you know how performance is with these two different approaches ?

Comment: the performance will be better if you filter out all redundant data on DB level(the way I suggested)

Comment: Thank you, Ive been reading up on queries in dynamo, and trying to create an index, tho it will not accept it. As I need deleted as a key schema element